# Make bootable flash drive of custom version of mikeOS

Tags: operating-system, kernel, nasm, bootloader, floppy

Using Hyper-V, I am running a Windows XP machine and I have a virtual floppy drive mounted too, where, using the following code, I am writing the bootloader.bin into the virtual floppy drive.

```
>debug
-n bootloader.bin
-l 0
-w 0 0 0 1
-quit
```

This is working well with a virtual floppy drive. I am compiling the asm files using NASM. However, I want to get my custom OS along with the new kernel.bin on a flash drive. Now, I saw that the mikeOS source has an ISO image, but I cannot get that on my flash drive using traditional methods, since it uses the own bootleader.

I am looking for a way in which I can get this OS working on any x86 PCs. I need a way to migrate the storage. Also, I do not wish to use a CD-R for this purpose. The memory should be rewritable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to put a raw floppy image (or bootloader) straight onto the USB. Use a raw burning program to do so. If you have your own VFD or ISO, you could use UNetbootin to put in onto the USB as it will assist in the booting process. If you have just the files, you could use Winimage to create a VFD or ISO with those files. If you feel stuck, go back to the MikeOS handbooks. They have a lot of helpful information.

**UPDATE**

In your case, you can easily use UNetbootin.

1. Download it for your platform (I assume Windows). You should have only **one** executable file.
2. Run the the executable file. NOTE: It isn't an installer. 
   [image]
3. Select 'diskimage' instead of 'Distribution'.
   [image]
4. Change 'ISO' to 'Floppy'.
   [image]
5. Select your VFD's location.
   [image]
6. Select the type of disk you want to write to. In this case, USB Drive is default.
   [image]
7. Select the drive, in this case drive `G:\`. **BE SURE THAT YOU PICK THE RIGHT ONE. THAT DRIVE WILL BE COMPLETELY WIPED BEFORE INSTALLATION!**
   [image]
8. Click OK. If everything goes good, you'll now have a bootable USB for your OS.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have a VFD image that I created by mounting it into a Windows XP virtual machine. I looked up UNetbootin, but it does not say anything about putting VFDs into USB.

Also, I am using a custom bootloader, and a custom MikeOS kernel. It all runs fine from the VFD. I would like to run that from the USB drive. I am not sure how UNetbootin will help.

Would you please post a step by step guide?

Answer (score 0):

"Format" it in assembly language, assemble, mount the image with [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) and copy the files over. This can all be done with a cmd script.
While you're at it take a look at [The 1.44MB FAT32 floppy disk](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=30339) and [MikeOS-4.5 FAT32 (16-bit real mode)](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=30326l) to see how simple it is to use FAT32 instead of FAT12.

PS. The formatting is done in bootload.asm in the MikeOS-4.5 FAT32 (16-bit real mode) distribution.